# Redirect page with anchor tag to a specific table row location

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamically table that it is incremented every time a new product is added to the database.

Each row of this table contains the name of the product, categories etc etc, it also contains a column with a link to another page, this link is only clicked if user wants to edit a specific product. Once user clicks on the link and makes the changes to the product they get redirect back to the product table page with an anchor tag of the row id clicked. The problem im facing is that I cant relocate the page back to where the user clicked the product.

I tested the anchors without redirecting pages and it does work, but once I add it to a different page it stop working. how can i fix this?

Page with table list:

```
$product_list .= "<tr id='$id'><th>$prod_cat</th><th>$sub_cat</th><th>$prod_name</th><th>$price</th><th>$q_left</th>
                 <th> $id1 </th><th> £$package </th><th><a href='dragNdrop.php?pID=$id'>Add more images</a>
                 &nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href='editProduct.php?pID=$id'>Edit</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
                 <a href='index.php?delID=$id&prodName=$prod_name'>Delete</a></th></tr>";

<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Product Category</th>
   <th>Sub-Cat</th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 <?php echo $product_list; ?>
</table>
```

edit product page:

```
<a href="index.php#354">Admin Home</a> (this will be a php echo with 
the id of the product/row but for simplicity i just added one of the rows id)
```

Comment: Nope its not. read it again!

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if editProduct.php is in the same folder with the php file that is rendering your table.

If yes, try Right clicking and inspect element the table and once located http://editProduct.php?pID=123 like that in the source code, copy the rendered link and open a new tab and paste the link if it appear.

Base from code it is correct and from deductions, it might be:

1.) The file is not in proper directory

2.) try hard coding the absolute link and see the result

Comment: Yes the file is in the same directory, if i right in the url #354 it does work, however if i cope the url and paste in a new window, it loads from top, i have to manually write the anchor in the url to get it working.

Comment: What do you mean when you said "if i cope the url and paste in a new window, it loads from top, i have to manually write the anchor in the url to get it working."? My English is not good. Anchor works like opening the file into a new window, if by that it failed, then there must be something in your PHP page that do it.

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrong, I mean if I copy the url www.something.com.file#anchor. it does not relocate to the position i want but if i am in the page www.something.com.file and i manually write in the url #anchor in front of the url link and press enter it will relocate me to the position I want. hope that makes sense

Comment: I see. The file you are rendering in the anchor doesn't have a defined host yet so it is best that you use the relative link like this example: <a href="/editProduct.php?id=id">Edit</a> or <a href = "/localhost:80/php/editProduct.php?id=id" for the temporary solution